# Are Handlebars helpers allowed to edit their context?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Now I don't mean block helpers that pass a different context to their children. No, I rather mean helpers that modify the context they're passed as their side effect.

Example and use-case:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('sortByFoo', function(elts) {
    elts.sort((elt1, elt2) => elt1.foo.localeCompare(elt2.foo));
    return "";
})

Handlebars.registerHelper('sortByBar', function(elts) {
    elts.sort((elt1, elt2) => (elt1.bar - elt2.bar));
    return "";
})

var context = {elements: [
    {foo: 'asdf', bar: 5},
    {foo: 'jkl', bar: 4}
]}

var source = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = template(context);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{sortByFoo elements}}
    <h2>Elements sorted by Foo:</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each elements}}
           <li>{{foo}}, {{bar}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{sortByBar elements}}
    <h2>Elements sorted by Bar:</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each elements}}
           <li>{{foo}}, {{bar}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Is this kind of stuff allowed on Handlebars? It seems to work in this snippet, but... The Handlebars documentation goes at great lengths about various ways to pass a different context to child elements, but says nothing about helpers being able to modify their own context and this makes me think that what I'm doing is perhaps not the intended usage of Handlebars and if it works it does only by accident - and that perhaps if I don't want to run into imminent trouble soon I should stop doing that.

Is such stuff allowed on Handlebars?

Comment: Sure it's allowed. Its just using javascript - you can do whatever you want. Is there a better way? Probably. Why don't you just have the helper that sorts the list and render each?

Comment: @realseanp How would I reference such a list returned from the helper in `each`?

Comment: btw, you not modifing the context, you mutating it. The mutation usualy not prevented and I see no problem to use it, while mutation itself usualy not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. I just took the hbs each helper, but added the sort functionality you have in your helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachSorted', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";
  var arr = context.slice();
  arr.sort((elt1, elt2) => elt1.foo.localeCompare(elt2.foo));

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn(arr[i]);
  }

  return ret;
});
```

Then

```
   {{#eachSorted elements}}
        <li>{{foo}}, {{bar}}</li>
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: The question is how is it different from my snippet since `arr.sort` sorts the array in place anyway?

Comment: `var arr = context.slice();` creates a new array